# Permanently disable OOM Killer for Postgres

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql-9.6

Following [this documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/kernel-resources.html#LINUX-MEMORY-OVERCOMMIT), I am trying to **permanently** disable OOM Killer for Postgres 9.6.2 on Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS.

In `/etc/init.d/postgresql`, I add:

```
echo -1000 > /proc/self/oom_score_adj
```

In `/etc/postgresql/9.6/main/environment`, I add:

```
PG_OOM_ADJUST_FILE='/proc/self/oom_score_adj'
PG_OOM_ADJUST_VALUE=0
```

I then restart the Postgres server, and the settings are applied correctly:

```
root# pid=`head -1 /var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main/postmaster.pid` && head /proc/$pid/oom*
==> /proc/12760/oom_adj <==
-17

==> /proc/12760/oom_score <==
0

==> /proc/12760/oom_score_adj <==
-1000
```

But when I restart my machine, the OOM values go back to default. How can I persist these changes?

Comment: Wouldn't you be better off fixing the underlying problem? IE: Get more memory?

Comment: @Philᵀᴹ Of course I need to fix the underlying problem, but to better handle future problems, I prefer to follow this recommendation: _"PostgreSQL servers should be configured without virtual memory overcommit so that the OOM killer does not run and PostgreSQL can handle out-of-memory conditions its self."_ http://stackoverflow.com/a/16430638/2091700